# how to pass image size if using html::image()

Tags: kohana

how can i specify height and width of an image if i use html::image() in koahana 3. if i pass all attributes in an array it says  that string expected instead of array ......please help

```
echo "<td class='".$class."' align='left' style='border-left:1px solid #D3D3D3'>
<a class='list_title' href='".$editBannerHref."'>".            
html::image(array("src"=>"media/uploads/video_portal thumbnail".$videos[$count]->image,"alt"=>"","width"=>60,"height"=>50))."</a><br/>
<a href='".$playVideo."'>View Video</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

First parameter is file name, second attributes - http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/HTML#image
This is the correct usage:

```
HTML::image("media/uploads/video_portal thumbnail".$videos[$count]->image, array("alt"=>"", "width"=>60, "height"=>50))
```